# One to one connection in OpenTok

Tags: chat, opentok, videochat

Looking at the samples of [**OpenTok**](https://tokbox.com/developer/) i have tried audio / video / chat session which acts like a chat room. When someone connects to my session, i am able to establish a connection (subscribe and publish) to it.

Is there any way to create a one to one connection where i can start a session for any particular user and then establish a connection to publish and subscribe to audio, video and text chat.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at the PresenceKit (one of the OpenTok Starter Kits): https://github.com/opentok/presencekit-php.

In this example, users can send invitations to chat with other users. The roster of users who are "online" is visible to all. This should be close to what you are after but since the code is open source and documented, you can make any modifications to implement the differences.

The example is in PHP with the JavaScript client, but should be easy to port to any server side language you may want to use.